# Как переиспользовать node_modules

Tags: javascript, node.js, phpstorm

У меня много различных проектов, и в каждом node_modules занимает 200+ мегабайт. Это быстро расходует место на ссд.
Как можно исправить эту ситуацию?
Вроде бы можно node_modules вынести в родительскую папку, тогда модули оттуда смогут быть использованны в других дочерних папках. Но тогда php storm не видит установленные в родительскую папку модули

Comment: А у вас во всех проектах одинаковые нод модули с одинаковыми версиями и тп?

Comment: Предыдущий комментарий имеет смысл, обычно в проектах разные версии. У меня была похожая идея когда-то я ее пытался реализовать через `софт линки` но в итоге оказалось что этого не достаточно, каждый модуль содержит подмодули иногда они очень хитро переплетены в проектах. Самое простое — удалять модули если проекты заморожены.

Comment: разве что глобально какие-то модули устанавливать.

Comment: используйте pnpm в качестве package manager https://pnpm.io/symlinked-node-modules-structure